# Starts With Character Does Not Match at Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex as like that:

```
/^[0-9]*.*K/
```

and I have a string to test:

```
L1/50K
```

and it matches. However it should match a string starts with a number? What is the explanation of that regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'*' means 0 or more. You have to use +, which means 1 or more

```
/^[0-9]+.*K/
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `*` after `[0-9]`. `*` repeats the previous (*token or character*) zero or more times, so if no number is present at the first, `^[0-9]*.*K` would match the string.

```
^\d\d*.*K$
```

OR

```
^\d+.*K$
```

OR

```
^\d{1,}.*K$
```

Use `\d` at the first so that it would match the strings which starts with a digit. Note `\d` is equal to `[0-9]`. `$` means end of the line, use this anchor after `K`, so that it would match the lines which starts with a number and ends with a `K`

Comment: What is the meaning of that `*`?

Comment: `*` repeats the previous token or character zero or more times.

Answer (score 0):

a * matches 0 or more of the preceding token.
if you want to force it to start with a number you should use a +, like:

```
/^[0-9]+.*K/
```

for excellent documentation on regexes, as well as build them:
http://www.regexr.com/